# Microsoft Bot - Manipulate user's input before it is injected into the bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am using Microsoft bot composer framework, and I want to change the user's input before it is injected into the bot. Can it be done?

The purpose of the change is to translate the user's input into English, because the language of the user's input is not supported by LUIS.

I was try to access the input in the controller, But I did not find where the input is stored in the existing objects there (like 'Request' or '_bot').

I do not want to do the translation inside the bot, because I want to use the input already for the trigger recognition.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

> I useing Microsoft bot composer framework, and I want to change the
> user's input before it is injected into the bot. Can it be done?

Not that explicitly. You cannot change it before it is received by the bot, but it can be modified by the bot before it does any other processing.

> The purpose of the change is to translate the user's input into
> English, because the language of the user's input is not supported by
> LUIS.
>
> I was try to access the input in the controller, But I did not find
> where the input is stored in the existing objects there (like
> 'Request' or '_bot').
>
> I do not want to do the translation inside the bot, because I want to
> use the input already for the trigger recognition. Thanks!

You'll want to look into [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Per the documentation:

"*Middleware provides you with additional opportunities to interact with your users' conversation flow both before and after each turn of the conversation is processed*"

I don't know that you'll be able to do exactly what you need to, but if it is possible; middleware is the way.